# Minimum distance from P (0,0) to the curve

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Which arrow corresponds to the minimum distance. I've this.

```
f[t_] := 1.5 + 0.95412 Exp[-(t/399.243)^0.500572] + 0.60082 Exp[-(t/601.739)^0.328243]

data = Table[{t, f[t]}, {t, 0, 18000}];

ListLinePlot[data,Ticks -> {Range[0, 18000, 2000], Range[0, 2, 0.05]}, 
Prolog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[{5000, 1.60858}]}, 
Epilog -> {Table[Arrow[{{0, 1.515}, {n, f[n]}}], {n, 3000, 8000, 500}]}]
```

[image]

This is my function to calculate de minimal distance bewteen two point, since 3000 to 8000, but the result is not correct. It give me around 3360.08 and by the graphic is 5000.

```
Min@Table[EuclideanDistance[{0, 1515}, {n, f[n]}], {n, 3000, 8000, 500}]
out:3360.08
```

The code of differences of slope is:

```
data = {{900, 1.903126}, {1800, 1.752655}, {2700, 1.7023}, {3600,1.64967}, {4500, 1.62171}, {5400, 1.59539}, {6300, 1.5773}, {7200,1.56414}, {8100, 1.56579}, {9000, 1.55592}, {9900, 1.55921}, {10800, 1.55263}, {11700, 1.5477}, {12600, 1.54441}, {13500, 1.54605}, {14400, 1.54276}, {15300,1.53783}, {16200, 1.53783}, {17100, 1.532461}, {18000, 1.525177}};

h[dx_, funcion_] := Module[{\[CapitalDelta]x = dx},
  dif = Differences[
    D[funcion, x] (x + \[CapitalDelta]x) - D[funcion, x] /. 
       x -> Range @@ {Min[#], Max[#]} &[First /@ data]];
  valorx = 
   Flatten@Cases[
     NSolve[D[funcion, x]*(x + \[CapitalDelta]x) - D[funcion, x] == 
       Min@dif, x, Reals], {_ -> x_ /; x > 0}]; b = x /. valorx;
  tangente[
    a_] := (funcion /. x -> a) + (D[funcion, x] /. x -> a) (x - a);
  Print[Style["RESUMEN", Black, Bold, 18]];
  Print["El valor mín de la diferencia de pendiente es = ", 
   ScientificForm @@ Min@dif] ; 
  Print["Su ubicación es el punto: P" , {b*10^4, 
    funcion /. x -> b*10^4}  ];
  Print["\n"];
  graf1 = 
   Plot[funcion, {x, Min[#] &[First /@ data], 
     Max[#] &[First /@ data]}, AxesStyle -> Thick, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Tau]\), \(*\)]\) vs \
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), \(*\)]\)" , 18, Black, 
      FontFamily -> "Kristen ITC"] ,
                             PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01], Blue}, 
    ImageSize -> 400,
    Epilog :> {  { Dashed, Thick, 
       Line[{{0, funcion /. x -> b*10^4}, {b*10^4, 
          funcion /. x -> b*10^4}, {b*10^4, 
          0}}]},(*linea discontinua*)
                          PointSize[0.02], Darker@Red, 
      Point[{b*10^4, funcion /. x -> b*10^4}],(*punto rojo*)  
                          Darker@Green, Arrowheads[0.03], 
      Arrow[{{(b*10^4) + 2050, (funcion /. x -> b*10^4) + 
          0.05}, {(b*10^4 + 300), (funcion /. x -> b*10^4) + 0.01}}],

      Style[Text[{b*10^4, 
         funcion /. x -> b*10^4}, {(b*10^4) + 
          4900, (funcion /. x -> b*10^4) + 0.05}], Black, Bold, 12]}];
  graf2 = 
   Plot[ Evaluate@tangente[b*10^4], {x, Min[#] &[First /@ data], 
     Max[#] &[First /@ data]}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}];
  graf3 = 
   Plot[ Evaluate@tangente[b*10^4 + \[CapitalDelta]x*1000], {x, 
     Min[#] &[First /@ data], Max[#] &[First /@ data]}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange}];
  Framed@Show[graf1, graf2, graf3]
  ]
```

My red point I get it from of this graphic.

[image]

Comment: "and by the graphic is 5000" That's an incorrect subjective assessment. You chose the red point arbitrarily. The scale of the horizontal and vertical axes is very different./

Comment: To add to what @Szabolcs said, there is also a typo: You wrote `1515` instead of `1.515`

Comment: I am aware that the axes are very different, that is why the reason for my doubt. The red dot I get from my difference of slopes I show below in my  code and I want to check with this method of arrows.

Comment: The vector of the min distance is (in your graph) not orthogonal to the function. If one defines `reg = ParametricRegion[{t, f[t]}, {{t, 0, 18000}}]` one gets a minimal distance of `RegionDistance[reg, {0, 1.515}]` value: 1.49, maybe I misunderstood something

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems more complicated than needed, but I wonder if I misunderstand your goal. Anyway, the following will find the point on the curve that is closest to the origin $(0,0)$:

```
minimum = NMinimize[EuclideanDistance[{0, 0}, {x, f[x]}], x]

(* Out: {2.9967, {x -> 0.284259}} *)
```

Graphically:

```
{mindist = #1, xmin = x /. #2} & @@ minimum;

Plot[
  Style[f[t], Thick, Black], {t, 0, 2},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 3.1}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Medium],
  Epilog -> {
    Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{xmin, f[xmin]}],
    Arrowheads[0.05],
    Table[
      Style[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {n, f[n]}}], Blend[{Red, Black}, Abs[(n - xmin)/xmin]^0.7]],
      {n, Range[0, 0.56, 0.07] ~ Join ~ {0.64, 0.74, 0.9, 1.1, 1.33, 1.6, 1.9}}
    ]
  }
]
```

[image: arrow plot]

Alternatively you can look at a plot of the distance itself:

```
Plot[
  EuclideanDistance[{0, 0}, {x, f[x]}], {x, 0, 1},
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, Axes -> False,
  PlotRangePadding -> Thread[Scaled[{0, 0.1}]],
  Epilog -> {
    Red, InfiniteLine[{{0, mindist}, {3, mindist}}],
    PointSize[0.02], Point[{xmin, mindist}]
  }
]
```

[image: distance plot]

Comment: It is not about the point that is closest to the origin. My goal is to find the arrow that represent the minimal distance to  experimental curve. According to my program this point is in the (4999.75,1.60859). See the graphic previous.

Comment: @Andres Could you explain exactly what kind of distance you are looking for then?

Comment: Knowing how to calculate this distance, can modify the code to find the minimum distance. This example may help.

Comment: `Manipulate[ ListLinePlot[data,Ticks -> {Range[0, 18000, 2000], Range[0, 2, 0.05]}, Prolog -> {Text[Style["Distance = ?", 14, Bold], {10000, 1.8}]}, 
  Epilog -> {Arrow[{{0, 1.515}, {n, f[n]}}]}],Row[{Control[{{n, 2000, "Values (Axes X)"}, 2000, 9000, 100}], " ", Dynamic[n]}]]`

Comment: In each positon, the arrow have a distance from the origin to the curve and, according to the previous graph of the arrows, it is observed that only one of them represents the shortest distance from the origin to the curve. The goal is to find this minimum distance.